# ANR when calling File.toURI()

Tags: java, android

The Google Play developer console, has reported that the File.toURI() method has caused an ANR (application not responding) error:

```
at libcore.io.Posix.stat(Native Method)
at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.stat(ForwardingOs.java:131)
at java.io.File.isDirectory(File.java:529)
at java.io.File.getAbsoluteName(File.java:1104)
at java.io.File.toURI(File.java:1062)
at com.mypackage.myclass.<init>(SourceFile:1234)
```

Is there an alternative way to do this on the main thread (because using a background thread seems like overkill)?

Comment: I doubt that File.toUri can cause a ANR. Also without take a look to the code it is impossible to understand what s going on.

Comment: File.toURI() is calling File.isDirectory() so it's not too surprising...

Answer (score 0):

Doing tasks directly on the UI or main thread is not recommended. In your case, try **AsyncTask**. Look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for an example.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to get the same result as File.toURI() without calling into the file system. For example, if I already know the File is a directory, then there is no need to (indirectly) call File.isDirectory()

Comment: @MarkCarter: AsyncTask is the way I know of eliminating ANR.

Comment: another way is to avoid unnecessary I/O. Please see my answer.

Comment: If you prefer to do it your way, then it's fine by me - but I wouldn't recommend it. For any file I/O, I would always do it in an `AsynTask`. :)

Comment: Of course, I/O should always be done in a background thread. But unnecessary I/O should not be done at all ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the file path is already an absolute path and you already know whether the File is a directory:

```
public static String toURI(File f, boolean isDirectory) {
    try {
        String sp = slashify(f.getPath(), isDirectory);
        if (sp.startsWith("//")) {
            sp = "//" + sp;
        }
        return new URI("file", null, sp, null);
    } 
    catch (URISyntaxException x) {
        throw new Error(x);         // Can't happen
    }
}

private static String slashify(String path, boolean isDirectory) {
    String p = path;
    if (File.separatorChar != '/')
        p = p.replace(File.separatorChar, '/');
    if (!p.startsWith("/"))
        p = "/" + p;
    if (!p.endsWith("/") && isDirectory)
        p = p + "/";
    return p;
}
```